# What is assigned to the variable updateSection in the offical sample code?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from offical sample code [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsRoute.kt).

`val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section) }` is a destructuring declaration.

It's a clear that `currentSection` is assigned by `tabContent.first().section`

What is assigned to the variable `updateSection`? Will it be assigned by `tabContent.first().content` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun InterestsRoute(
   ...
) {
    val tabContent = rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel)
    val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }
    ...
}


@Composable
fun rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel): List<TabContent> {  
    val uiState by interestsViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val topicsSection = TabContent(Sections.Topics) {
        val selectedTopics by interestsViewModel.selectedTopics.collectAsState()
        TabWithSections(
            sections = uiState.topics,
            selectedTopics = selectedTopics,
            onTopicSelect = { interestsViewModel.toggleTopicSelection(it) }
        )
    }
     ...
    return listOf(topicsSection, peopleSection, publicationSection)
}


enum class Sections(@StringRes val titleResId: Int) {
    Topics(R.string.interests_section_topics),
    People(R.string.interests_section_people),
    Publications(R.string.interests_section_publications)
}

class TabContent(val section: Sections, val content: @Composable () -> Unit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateSection` is a lambda here used to update the value of the mutable state.
Consider this example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyButton() {
    val (count, updateCount) = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Button(
        onClick = { updateCount(count+1) }
    ) {
        Text(text = "$count")
    }
}
```

Here count is `Int` and updateCount is `(Int) -> Unit`. updateCount takes an `Int` and updates the value of the MutableState (`count`) to the provided value (here `count+1`).
The above code updates the count text by one everytime the button is clicked.

Coming back to your code, `rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf (...) }` creates a new MutableState. Its initial value will be `tabContent.first().section`. `currentSection` stores the value of this MutableState (initially it will be `tabContent.first().section`). Now if you want to update the value of this MutableState you can use the `updateSection` lambda. Just invoke that lambda with the new value and `currentSection` will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks! In your code, `updateCount` is `(Int) -> Unit`, how can you know the function `updateCount` will update the value of the `MutableState (count) `?  It's  built-in function of Android Studio?

Comment: And more, in your code `onClick = { updateCount(count+1) }` is equivalent to `onClick = { count=count+1 }`, right?

Comment: So in a sense, I needn't the function `updateCount`, I can reassign data to `count` by myself directly, right?

Comment: You can directly reassign to `count` if you make it a `var`. In my code I used a `val` so I needed `updateCount` to update the MutableState.

Comment: For your question on whether it's a built-in function, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot4Cv.png) is a section from the implementation of MutableState. These component functions have been overridden here.